# Is my ADSL2+ speed locked by an ISP?

Tags: adsl

I signed a contract with my ISP for ADSL and internet speed should be 16 mbps.
However, speedtest.net says I have only 7.5 mbps.

Here's the router info:
SNR Margin: 16.8
Line Attenuation: 25.0
Data Rate: 8192 kbps
Max Rate: 16972 kbps

Does it mean that ISP has locked my internet speed to 8 mbps, and what's the max speed that I can get based on these statistics?

Thank you!

Comment: Ask your ISP. Seriously, how can any of us be expected to know what their configurations or policies are?

Comment: Is your router ADSL2+? Your speed seems to be limited by something, either your CPE, or from your provider.

Comment: I just need to know what Data Rate and Max Rate mean? I called the support, and operator doesn't know what to answer because he's reading the answers from some paper. Sad but true. So, do you know what is the max. internet speed that I get based on Max Rate, SNR margin, and Line Attenuation

Comment: Yes, this it is possible for them to do this, but the speed also depends on the wiring quality in your house, and the phone line quality between your ADSL modem and their equipment at the central office. You will need to ask your ISP for details.

Comment: @Stefan, Is Max Rate the maximum speed that my line can handle (w/o overhead)?

Comment: @šljaker Serverfault.com is not a good place to ask ADSL questions. You might want to check the answers on superuser.com . Here's good place to start: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dsl?sort=votes

Answer (score 1):

You probably ought to do a bit of research on how traffic actually moves around the internet.

That bandwidth figure your ISP gives you is **only** for traffic between your modem and their DSLAM, or perhaps their core routing layer. Once traffic goes beyond that (e.g. to the speedtest.net server), they have no control over it.